# Can't boot from USB stick, black screen with cursor

Tags: linux, boot, manjaro, bootable

I’m trying to install Manjaro Gnome minimal stable on my new laptop but I can’t boot it from usb. Until menu everything works fine, but after I choose to boot manjaro it shows me some operations  and then just a black screen with the cursor on the up left corner(or sometimes black screen with mouse pointer)
TTY works fine. USB and image is fine(I installed Manjaro from it to my PC without problem)

I tried :

- To boot with open source drivers
- To bemove quiet
- To install Manjaro KDE instead

Nothing helped

Additional info:

- journalctl output https://0x0.st/-yOE.txt
- inxi output https://0x0.st/-yOR.txt
- startx from TTY shows Manjaro hello menu with lots of visual artifacts, then system freezes and after 5-10 seconds error screen appears(A problem has occured and system can't recover. Please log out and try again). Error screen has visual artifacts too. If booted without quiet then startx fails with errors Could not resolve ***

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the installer linux kernel is too old for your laptop, so you could try finding a newer installation image or use another distro with a more up to date kernel. You could try booting with `nomodeset` and install - hopefully a newer kernel gets installed which is compatible with your laptop. Yeah, and remove `nouveau.modeset=1 i915.modeset=1 radeon.modeset=1`

Your laptop has switchable NVIDIA graphics, so blacklisting `nouveau` could also help.

Also make sure you've familiarized with https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Optimus_Manager